# error running the current program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, ide

I have written a new code and clicked run. after clicking run, the console shows the previous program again. I have restarted eclipse and even my computer. This happens very often to my IDE. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you select the right compilation unit in the package explorer (same name as the `public class`)?

Comment: what is Right compilation unit? I tried the run button (looks like green play button) . I have also run from the package explorer.

Comment: Do you have that class selected in the 'Package Explorer' or the 'Project Explorer'? Chances are, you have your old class selected there.

Comment: In the package explorer, click on the file named `practice29`. Then click run.

Comment: thanks a lot :) . It worked. . . .

Comment: The black downwards arrow shows all the recent run configurations. Use that to select the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try right click on the editor and chose 'Run As' >> 'Run Configurations' and check if you run the right compilation package.
It seems that for some reason your eclipse runs the wrong one.

Comment: worked. Thanks. . . . .

Comment: @AsifSabir If it worked I'll appreciate if you'll accept the answer.